# Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.ParseDecimal DB2. Executedataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc, db2

I am getting this exception when I try to executedataset in a db2 server.
The weirdest thing is that the Unit Test code doesnt throw the exception, but when I try to call it from the webpage with the same parameters then it throws the exception.

Here is my unit test code:

```
[Test]
        public void Get_the_car_details_via_the_chassisnumber_WVWZZZ1KZCW240208()
        {
            //Arrange
            string chassisNumber = "WVWZZZ1KZCW240208";

            string brand = "skoda";


            //Act
            Vehicle car = VehicleDA.GetVehicle(chassisNumber, "", brand).GetResult();

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(car);
            car.Type.ShouldBe("VOLKSWAGEN GOLF");

        }
```

Here is how I call it from the page, as you can see I hardcoded the same parameter and it still doesnt work

```
public Vehicle GetVehicleInformation(string chassis, string commissionnumber, string brand)
        {
            Vehicle car = VehicleDA.GetVehicle("WVWZZZ1KZCW240208", commissionnumber, "skoda").GetResult();
```

Here is the DB code in the dal

```
public class VehicleDA
    {
        public static ResultForType<Vehicle> GetVehicle(string chassisNumber, string commissionNumber, string brand)
        {

            if (chassisNumber.Length != 17 && chassisNumber.Length > 0)
            {
                chassisNumber = new ChassisNumberSearch().GetCompleteChassisNumber(chassisNumber);
                if (chassisNumber == string.Empty)
                {
                    return CreateReturnWithError("Unknown chassis number");
                }
            }


            if (chassisNumber == string.Empty)
            {
                chassisNumber = GetTheLatestChassisNumberInCaseOfMultipleChassisNumbers(new ChassisNumberSearch().GetChassisNumber(commissionNumber));
                if (chassisNumber == string.Empty)
                {
                    return CreateReturnWithError("Unknown commision number");
                }
            }



            var vehicleXMLString = new VehicleSearch().GetVehicle(chassisNumber);

            if (GetDateTimeDataFor("DFACUSI", vehicleXMLString) < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
            {
                return CreateReturnWithError("Vehicle is older then 2 years");
            }

            if ( GetDateTimeDataFor("DFACTUR", vehicleXMLString) == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return CreateReturnWithError("Invoice date is not filled in");
            }


            var vehicle = new Vehicle
                                  {
                                      Chassis = chassisNumber,
                                      ComissionNumber = GetDataFor("NCOMMIS", vehicleXMLString),
                                      Type = GetDataFor("LMAKTYP", vehicleXMLString),
                                      Year = GetIntDataFor("CANNMOD", vehicleXMLString),
                                      OrderDate = GetDateTimeDataFor("D705DAT", vehicleXMLString),
                                      InvoiceDate = GetDateTimeDataFor("DFACTUR", vehicleXMLString),
                                      InvoiceNumber = GetDataFor("NFACTUR", vehicleXMLString),
                                      DeliveryDate = GetDateTimeDataFor("DLIVRAI", vehicleXMLString),
                                      RegistrationDate = GetDateTimeDataFor("DIMMFIR", vehicleXMLString),
                                      CataloguePrice = GetDecimalDataFor("VPRICAT", vehicleXMLString),
                                      InvoicePrice = GetDecimalDataFor("VPRIFAC", vehicleXMLString),
                                      Code = GetDataFor("CINTERM", vehicleXMLString)

                                  };

            var result = new ResultForType<Vehicle>(vehicle);
            if (!vehicle.Type.ToLower().StartsWith(brand.ToLower()))
            {
                result.AddWarning("Brand of the dealer is different from the brand of the vehicle");
            } 

            if (vehicle.RegistrationDate < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
            {
                result.AddWarning("Registration date is older then 3 months");
            }

            //"Registration date is older then 3 months"



            return result;
        }

 public class VehicleSearch : DB2Base
    {
        public string GetVehicle(string chassisNumber)
        {
            const string procName = "CALL DBSP.xxx(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            var cmd = DB2Database.GetStoredProcCommand(procName);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (chassisNumber.Length > 17)
            {
                chassisNumber = chassisNumber.Substring(0, 17);
            }

            CreateInputParameter("CFONCTI", cmd, "RB");
            CreateInputParameter("CFORMAT", cmd, "X");
            CreateInputParameter("CLANGUE", cmd, "E");
            CreateInputParameter("FEXTEND", cmd, "Y");
            CreateInputParameter("NCHASSI", cmd, chassisNumber);
            CreateStringParameter("LLIGXML", cmd, 250);
            CreateStringParameter("CIDFVAR", cmd, 10);
            CreateStringParameter("LVALVAR", cmd, 250);
            CreateStringParameter("CEQUIPE", cmd, 4);
            CreateStringParameter("CEQUPAC", cmd, 4);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQUCOUF", cmd, 30);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQUCOUN", cmd, 30);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQUCOUD", cmd, 30);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQUCOUE", cmd, 30);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQULONF", cmd, 120);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQULONN", cmd, 120);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQULOND", cmd, 120);
            CreateStringParameter("LEQULONE", cmd, 120);
            CreateStringParameter("CTYPOPT", cmd, 1);
            CreateStringParameter("CCATOPT", cmd, 1);
            CreateStringParameter("CEQUGEN", cmd, 4);
            CreateDecimalParameter("VHTVAXX", cmd, 10);
            CreateStringParameter("CRETOUR", cmd, 2);
            CreateStringParameter("LMSGERR", cmd, 70);
            CreateStringParameter("LSPPROG", cmd, 8);
            CreateStringParameter("LSPPARG", cmd, 30);
            CreateSmallIntParameter("CSPRETC", cmd, 2);
            CreateIntParameter("CSQLAST", cmd, 4);
            CreateStringParameter("LSQLMSG", cmd, 70);

            var dataset = DB2Database.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            if (dataset.HasRowsInTheFirstTable())
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    result.Append(row[0]);
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Also hardcode the commissionnumber to be "" and see if works then.

Comment: I changed the dataset with datareader and it looks its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what the problem was, but changing the ExecuteDataSet with ExecuteDatareader worked fine.